# have django models come with defaults

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some Django models that my site relies on *very* heavily, it dose not even matter what is in the models just that there is something in them. 2 of my pages get markdown data from the models and then convert them to HTML and display it on the page. I tried messing around with the default parameters in some of the models but I still have to go by the admin dashboard to set things up. Is there a way that I can have the database come with pre-setup objects when I run `python manage.py migrate`?

my models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class apikey(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(default="")

class video(models.Model):
    official_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    vid = models.CharField()
    thumbnail_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    biblestudy = models.BooleanField()
```

this is the models file from my other app

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class message(models.Model):
    visitmessage = models.TextField(default="# hi")
    ourvision = models.TextField(default="# hi")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to do it in the migrate stage, but you can pre-define a django command to create some objects.

Check out [commands in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)

So you might have something like, in it's most basic form:

app/management/commands/create_vids.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from app.models import video


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        
        #If you want random values, check out the Faker module
        Video.objects.create(
            official_name="video 1"
            ...
        )
        Video.objects.create(
            official_name="video 2"
            ...
         )
```

which you can then call with

```
python manage.py create_vids
```

To further develop, you could add arguments that called either a create or destroy function, rather than just having the one handle() method.